# Check if cells in row are empty, if false print other cells

Tags: excel

I want to check in a row, if there is anything in the cells and for all cells that have any value, I want to print the cell two rows above. The formula also should print a comma between the printed cell values. Let me try to show in a table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPQcR.png

I need a formula to check in row 2 from A-E whether the cells are empty or not and if not, I need to print the words above in row 1.
In my example the formula should print: "butter, sirup and water".

Comment: Where do you want the result printed to?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply use =() referencing the cell below? I'd need a bit more context as to what you're doing/ what you're after to work out what sort of function you'd need

Comment: I want to check all the cells A-E in row 2, and for every cell that has any content, I want to print the cell above with a comma. I don't want the function to end looking for the cells B-E, if there is content in A2. I need them to add up.

Comment: This formula solves a part of the problem:

=INDEX(A1:E1;MATCH("content";A2:E2;0))    --> leads to "butter"

It gives me the value above the cell it found "content" in. But then it stops. I don't know how to add more cells - to make it not only print "butter" but "butter, sirup, water".

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Following your example I will do this: 
In cell A3(for example) the following formula:

```
   =+IF(A2<>"";A1&A2&",";"")
```

And extend it through the row. 
Then in cell A4 the concatenation:

```
   =A3&B3&C3&D3&E3
```